# Suggestions on how to learn more about deep learning for who is already familiar with machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am familiar with machine learning and I am looking for suggestions on how to deepen my understanding of deep neural networks.

I would say that I have a good practical and theoretical understanding of support vector machines, decision trees, and hidden Markov models. I know the basics of feed-forward neural networks and the backpropagation algorithm, but I would like to get a deeper understanding of NN architectures. I would like to understand better the pros and cons of different activation function and other hyperparameters. My focus area is bioinformatics so suggestions relevant to the field would be plus. I have only a vague idea of CNNs, RNNs, and so on. A structured introduction to the topic would be appreciated.

Thanks for your help!